# how do i select the row with the largest day in SQL

Tags: sql

Hello I have this query to the database:

```
select DISTINCT(CO_GID),
max(last_modified ) as DIA,
TRX_INI_FREQUENCY as TRX
from C_BSC_TRX ,UTP_COMMON_OBJECTS 
where (OBJ_GID = CO_GID)  
and (CO_GID LIKE '114481%')
GROUP BY CO_GID,TRX_INI_FREQUENCY



CO_GID   DIA           TRX
```

---

```
114481  07/11/18       null 
114481  27/10/18        49
114481  22/06/20        96
```

the problem is that I only want the row to be returned with the most current date: in this case it would be 06-22-2020
and the group by prevents me because I have to put the TRX_INI_FREQUENCY in the group by

what I wanted to get would be:

```
CO_GID   DIA           TRX
```

---

```
114481  22/06/20        96
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `keep` to get the last value of `trx`:

```
select CO_GID,
       max(last_modified) as DIA,
       max(TRX_INI_FREQUENCY) keep (dense_rank first order by last_modified desc) as TRX
from C_BSC_TRX JOIN
    UTP_COMMON_OBJECTS 
    on OBJ_GID = CO_GID and CO_GID LIKE '114481%'
group by CO_GID;
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.
- Qualify column names!  It is quite unclear what columns come from which tables.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're using, Add SELECT TOP 1 and ORDER BY DIA DESC

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 DISTINCT(CO_GID),
max(last_modified ) as DIA,
TRX_INI_FREQUENCY as TRX
from C_BSC_TRX ,UTP_COMMON_OBJECTS 
where (OBJ_GID = CO_GID)  
and (CO_GID LIKE '114481%')
GROUP BY CO_GID,TRX_INI_FREQUENCY
Order by DIA desc
```